# Twig set a variable name with a variable [TWIG/PHP]

Tags: php, variables, twig

How can I set a variable's name with the value of another value in Twig?
I would think that It would go something like this:

```
{% set queCount = loop.index %}
{% for row2 in answer+queCount %}
```

But this does not work. Also making a string from that will break the loop (because it does not search for a string).
I know how to do this in PHP so for clarification, this is what I would like to achieve:

```
$count = 1;
$args["answer$count"]
```

which returns

```
$args["answer1"]
```

But this time, not with strings but the operant answer.

Thanks in advance!
Mats de Waard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*You can use the `_context` variable*

```
{% set queCount = loop.index %}
{% for row2 in _context['answer' ~ queCount] %}
```

*Here is [the doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#global-variables) about _context and global variables*

Comment: I would think that would work, but it does not seem to. Is there any way to see what what value is? (With a echo/print of some sort?) so that I can give more info on what is not working?

Comment: In your template, type `{{ dump(_context) }}`

Comment: there were a small typo, i edited so @MatsdeWaard you can try again now. Put1 i love your nickname, btw; imagining you telling "hey dude here is my SO account, check it out" during an interview. :P

Comment: @AlainTiemblo Thanks mate! This works like a charm! +1 :D I did not think that answer could be a string. I thought that it had to not be one. Thanks you :)

Comment: @AlainTiemblo Thank You xD It's what I say every day about my own code. But for an interview it's not important now, I've got a small diploma (bac+6 month) and in France I'm not considered as a *true* dev. PS0 : Thanks for your edit, PS1 : Thank you for your work (twig fiddle) !  PS2: You've decrypted my nickname, so sorry to be impolite....

Answer (score 0):

In these cases you must use the `attribute()` function:

```
{% for row2 in attribute(args, 'answer' ~ queCount) %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

More information: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html

Comment: This would not solve the problem that I am having, since I simply want to add the value of queCount to the operator: "answer" (args would not be involved).

Answer (score 0):

If the environment option `strict_variables` is set to `true` (the default value is `false`, [see docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#environment-options)), @pbenard's answer will cause a fatal error if a variable doesn't exist. For example, if `answer3` doesn't exist, you get something like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Runtime: Key "answer3" for array with keys "answer1, answer2, row, queCount, _parent, _seq, loop, _key" does not exist in "index" at line 9.

When the option is set to `false`, unexisting variables are silently defaulted to `null`. (That's why you don't get the error.)

You can avoid the problem by providing a default value with the `default` filter:

```
{% set queCount = loop.index %}
{% for row2 in _context['answer' ~ queCount]|default(null) %}
```

You can also omit the value and even the parentheses. The variable will then default to an empty string. The end result is the same because both `null` and an empty string are falsey values, so they are skipped in the `for` loop. I.e. these two are equal and valid:

```
{% for row2 in _context['answer' ~ queCount]|default() %}

{% for row2 in _context['answer' ~ queCount]|default %}
```

I'd argue that generally it's better to set `strict_variables` to `true` to avoid accidental errors caused by e.g. typos in variable names. Even if it's set to `false`, using the `default` filter in cases like this is a good thing to do so that you can later set the option to `true` without worrying about breaking existing code.